# Hibernate set constraint "ON UPDATE CASCADE"

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, cascade

If you want to use a foreign key with a *ON DELETE CASCADE* you can do that in hibernate using the `@OnDelete` annotation. It forces hibernate to generate a DDL for the table with a proper foreign key constraint.

What I'm now looking for is a possibility to tell hibernate to create a constraint with *ON UPDATE CASCADE*. Unfortunately there is no `@OnUpdate` annotation in hibernate.
How can I tell hibernate to generate the DDL for the table with an *ON UPDATE CASCADE* constraint for the foreign key?

Comment: It is generally not a good idea to update primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the @Cascade annotation?

```
@Cascade(CascadeType.SAVED_UPDATE)
```

Comment: The cascade annotation has unfortunately no impact when hibernate generates the CREATE TABLE DDL.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the hibernate native API , then you should use the annotation of hibernate for cascade and it is :

**> @Cascade(CascadeType.SAVED_UPDATE)**

then you call save() method but with your annotation , you should call the method persist() of the JPA
Please check hibernate documentation for more details.

> http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-cascade

Following are some cascade operations which may be useful.

> CascadeType.PERSIST : means that save() or persist() operations
>        cascade to related entities.
>
> CascadeType.MERGE : means that related
>        entities are merged into managed state when the owning entity is
>        merged.
>
> CascadeType.REFRESH : does the same thing for the refresh()
>        operation.
>
> CascadeType.REMOVE : removes all related entities
>        association with this setting when the owning entity is deleted.
>
> CascadeType.DETACH : detaches all related entities if a “manual
>        detach” occurs.
>
> CascadeType.ALL : is shorthand for all of the above
>        cascade operations.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help me. What I want is to get the right DDL when hibernate creates the table. The foreign key constraint should look like: ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE. This isn't the case when I use the solution you recommended. I want to use database tools (pgAdmin) to modify the rows, therefore I need a solution where hibernate creates the table with the right constraints for the foreign keys.